# Making memory functions buttons for a calculator app

Tags: objective-c, ios, calculator

I am making a calculator app and want to make two memory functions buttons
 ("add to memory" or "**remember**" and "display the remembered" or "**tell**")

The way I get the current value on the main label is

```
double currentValue = [screenLabel.text doubleValue];
```

Basically, how could I get some kind of a memory cache that would allow me to make

- the first button that clears the special memory of its cache, reads the label and stores it as long as needed but not permanently
- the second button that reads the stored value from the cache and displays it, or displays 0 in case no value is stored

?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You hardly want us to write your code. There must be some specific problem or maybe a number of them. Don't you know how to associate a button with a method so that some code is executed when you press the button? Or don't you know how to store some number that reprensents the value of your calculator's memory? Or don't you know how to set the text of a label?

Comment: @ValKalinic - your question is still unclear. You want something which stores a value in your program but not permanently and starts off at zero, well `double memoryValue = 0;` clearly does that so that is presumably not what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get what you are asking for. So you look for a persistant storage that presevers its content even when the app is terminated and re-launched later? And there is just this one number that you want to store?

Comment: @HermannKlecker thank you for your comments guys; yes, just one number, that is originally 0 but changes to the value of screenLabel.text with button1 and updates screenLabel.text with itself (gets displayed) with button2, the value should be preserved as long as the app is active or in the background, just one number, where should I start, how to declare it to begin?

Comment: @ValKalinic By the way, you're asking about the "memory" buttons on a calculator: But, if you're having questions on this, I'm really wondering how you're handling a series of user input like "2 + 8 * 5". The right answer is 42 (because you save the 2, multiply 8 times 5, and then add the two back to the product). Getting values from a `UILabel` just won't do it. You need rich model structures to store this sort of information. It gets even more interesting if you supported calculations like "6 * (5 + (7 / (4.5 - 1)))", which quickly gets to needing something like nmock's stack concept.

Comment: @Rob, I guess that Val is trying to extend his first tutorial/example code and tries to find this way though it without having some basics of objective-c understood. If I am sort of right then your answer below is what he is looking for as well as CRD's answer leads into the right direction. The Answer of Life2Enjoy7 is one step too much (my opinion). But an NSDictionary could be used as some quick-n-dirty way of making one or a hand full of data persistant. I am thinking of the writeToFile and dicitionaryWithContentsOfFile methods.

Comment: @Rob I didn't quite get to using parentheses yet, I'll look into that, thank You. Everyone, thank You all very much for Your kind answers, I'll try it all now and accept/reply as needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have suggested, you need some model structure (e.g. some class properties) to keeping track of where you are in your calculation. But if you need to keep track of your calculator's memory register, you might have a property like:

```
@property (nonatomic) double memoryValue;
```

So you would just take that property, e.g. `memoryValue`, and either add to it, subtract from it, clear it (set it to zero), or retrieve its value, depending upon whether the user hit <kbd>m+</kbd>, <kbd>m-</kbd>, <kbd>mc</kbd>, or <kbd>mr</kbd>, respectively. I would personally even contemplate a `NSNumber` property, but I don't think you need to go there.

Maybe I'm not understanding your question.

---

I have to confess that I was more worried by your line of code where you're getting your `currentValue` from `screenLabel.text`. You really do *not* want to retrieve data that is intrinsic to the operation of your app from a user-interface control like a `UILabel`, which is solely designed for the presentation of information. This implies a fundamental confusion about how MVC, or [Model-View-Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html), apps are designed. The values that drive the calculations (e.g. the current value, the memory value, etc.) are part of the *model* (possibly stored as properties of some `model` object). The `UILabel` that presents the currently calculated value, is part of the *view.*

It's not a good idea to use the `UILabel` (part of the *view*) to drive calculations. Your app should be maintaining a *model* for the app's data/operations, and the *view* should just be a presentation of that *model* (not the other way around).

A calculator app is a wonderful example of the practical considerations here. For example, your calculator may have a "scientific/exponential notation mode" (where 1,200,000,000 might be displayed as "1.2e9"). Or maybe it's displaying the numeric value with a comma as a thousand's separator (where one million is displayed as "1,000,000.00"). The formatting of the `text` property of the `UILabel` could be driven by a variety of different factors, and you really shouldn't be worrying about the string formatting when using `double` values for calculation purposes.

Another great example is the number of digits shown is a function of whether the app is in landscape orientation (where we have space for lots of decimal places) versus portrait orientation (less space and therefore fewer decimal places shown). The app shouldn't remember fewer digits just because there was less space to show them on the portrait-oriented screen. The actual calculated values in the underlying *model* shouldn't change as the user interface of the *view* changes. And, regardless, the *model* probably will always use more "significant digits" that you'll ever want to present in a user interface.

But hopefully these examples drive home the distinction between your app's *model* and the *view.* In short, it's not prudent to retrieve values from `UILabels`. Keep the real values (no pun intended) in your app's *model.*

Answer (score 2):

A stack data object in your model would be able to persist values in memory.

Check out this category:
http://saturnboy.com/2011/02/stack-queue-nsmutablearray/

Answer (score 1):

Still guessing what your problem really is, here is an answer to what you appear to have asked...

Your calculator presumably has an add button, and addition requires two operands. Your question indicates that one of those is stored in `screenLabel` as text and `currentValue` as a number. Where is the other one? Store your memorised value in a variable in the same object you store that second value.

E.g. you'll have something like this:

```
@implementation MyCalculator
{
   double currentValue;
   double previousValue;
   double memoryValue;
   ...
}

...

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

use an NSMutableDictionary where your first button will setObjectForKey and the other button will removeObjectForKey.

You can also set up a singleton class with one instance of this dictionary to make it available to other classes. Depends on your structure.